# R: Plotting sample size against power

Tags: r, statistics, sample

Hi I am trying to plot sample size against power in R.
I think it would require a for loop but do not know how to implement this correctly.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
 for (i in c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)){
   graph<-power.prop.test(p1=0.4,p2=0.24,power=c(0.1:1),sig.level=0.05)}

    plot(graph$n,graph$power,type="b",xlab="sample size",ylab="power")
```

Comment: You should ask yourself whether it makes any statistical sense to request a value for `n` when power =1. You should also learn to use indexing on the left side of assignments inside for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `power.t.test` and `power.prop.test` functions in R don't behave nicely with vectorized arguments so you need to wrap the call in a loop-like construct as you suggest.

Below I use the `sapply` function for iterations and extract the sample size, which is then used for plotting.

```
powrange <- seq(0.4, .9, .1)
n <- sapply(powrange, function(i) power.prop.test(p1=0.4,p2=0.24,power=i,sig.level=0.05)$n)
plot(n, powrange, type="b",xlab="sample size",ylab="power")
```

If you don't extract `n` then you end up with a list of output results and you'd need to iterate over the output to get `n` from that.